# Django - Understanding RelatedManager remove method

Tags: python, django

So here I will be using classic Django Blog and Entry models from the documentation ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/)). I added `null=True` to the Entry's blog attribute.

```
>>> cb = Blog.objects.get(name__startswith="Cheese")
>>> gouda = Entry.objects.get(headline__startswith="Gouda")
>>> cb.entry_set.all()
[<Entry: Gouda>, <Entry: Emmentaler>]
>>> cb.entry_set.remove(gouda)
>>> gouda.blog
<Blog: Cheese blog>
```

I know that everything is fine and updated in database and if I query the second line from my example again that `gouda.blog` is gonna return `None`, but my question is why is `gouda.blog` not `None` without another query?

EDIT:

So if I understand everything correctly, this is how it works:

```
>>> cb = Blog.objects.get(name__startswith="Cheese")
>>> gouda = Entry.objects.get(headline__startswith="Gouda")
>>> cb.entry_set.all()
[<Entry: Gouda>, <Entry: Emmentaler>]
>>> cb.entry_set.remove(gouda)
>>> gouda.blog
<Blog: Cheese blog>
```

So default value of the `bulk` argument for the `remove()` method is `True`. That means that `QuerySet.update()` will be used. Object `gouda` will not be altered at the Python level so the `blog` attribute will still hold primary key of the "Cheese blog" blog. When we query `gouda.blog`, we will still get the "Cheese blog" object.

But what happens when `bulk=False` is passed to `remove()`? From documentation: If bulk=False, the save() method of each individual model instance is called instead.

So then I override `save()` method of the `Entry` model like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.blog == None:
        print(id(self))
```

and then:

```
>>> cb = Blog.objects.get(name__startswith="Cheese")
>>> gouda = Entry.objects.get(headline__startswith="Gouda")
>>> cb.entry_set.all()
[<Entry: Gouda>, <Entry: Emmentaler>]
>>> id(gouda)
139797518743592
>>> cb.entry_set.remove(gouda, bulk=False)
139797518745552
>>> gouda.blog
<Blog: Cheese blog>
```

Now we see that `gouda` object that `save()` method is called on is not the same as the one in our shell, so our object in the shell still holds primary key of "Cheese blog" in its `blog` attribute. And when we query for the blog with `gouda.blog` we still get "Cheese blog" object.

Is that correct and if it is, why is `save()` not called on the same object that we passed to `remove()`?

Answer (score 2):

You've said it yourself, you need to go back to the database to get the new information. The `gouda` object doesn't automatically keep a link to its database row; it only queries it when told to do so.